# Linking external javascript and css files into Vue component?

Tags: node.js, vuejs2

I created a functional chess board using javascript and CSS. I want to use it in a Vue app but I can't figure out how to link the javascript and CSS files to the component. Is there a way to load them in webpack, or what is the correct way of going about this?

Comment: If u use webpack and babel, u can import them like modules

Answer (score 1):

this should help

```
<style scoped>
    @import '../assets/css/custom.css';
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just follow this tutorial and configure webpack for your project.

http://todarman.com/configuring-webpack-es6-sass/

After configuring the webpack.config.js file, open terminal in your project directory, and run the command npm run dev. I will build the js and css files in their respective directories. You can link the files into your index.html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Webpack index page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>webpack configuration</h2>

  <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.